# retrieve selected text when click on context menu

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made a context menu, and simply I want to retrieve the selected text to the extension when I click on this context to execute certain function like:

```
dosomething(txt){
//alert message for example
alert(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using the following:

```
function genericOnClick(info, tab)
{
    alert(info.selectionText);
}
```